# How the determinant changes if we alter a given mapping on certain vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

Given linearly independent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and linearly independent vectors $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ and a mapping $A$ such that
$$
 w_i = Av_i, \quad i = 1,\ldots, n
$$ 
then if I define a mapping $B$ by $Bv_k := \lambda A v_k$ for some $1 \le k \le n$
and $Bv_i = Av_i$ otherwise, then $\det B = \lambda \det A$. I want to prove this using just the abstract properties of the determinant as for example mentioned [here on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Abstract_algebraic_aspects).

I know that in terms of matrices we have
$$
 B = CA
$$
where $C$ is the matrix with $c_{kk} = \lambda$ and $c_{ii} = 1$ if $i \ne k$ and $c_{ij} = 0$ if $i \ne k$ (like the identity expect at the $k$-diagonal entry). Then $\det(B) = \det(C)\det(A) = \lambda\det(A)$, but I want to avoid talking about matrices (which in turn needs bases). Are there any elegant abstract, preferable coordinate-free, arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\det(A)$ by $$\underline A(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) = \det(A)v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$$ Then $$\begin{align}\det(B)v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n &= \underline B(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) \\ &= w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_{k-1} \wedge \lambda w_k \wedge w_{k+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge w_n \\ &= \lambda w_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge w_n \\ &= \lambda \underline A(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) \\ &= \lambda \det(A)v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n\end{align}$$

Therefore $\det(B) = \lambda\det(A)$.$\ \ \ \ \ \square$

Coordinate-free and beautiful.  You gotta love exterior algebra.

Comment: I guess that $A(v_1\wedge \ldots \wedge v_n)=A(v_1)\wedge\ldots \wedge A(v_n)$, right?

Comment: That is correct.  See [Wikipedia's entry on outermorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outermorphism) for more info.

Comment: Ohh I am not that familiar with exterior algebra, I have to learn that!